File upload bypass mechnisms in PHP
I am learning file upload bypass mechanisms in PHP, which include multiple techniques, such as bypassing extensions, mime types, and adding magic bytes.
I have a simple script (copied from chatGPT) that validates the extension.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

    $allowedTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'];
    print_r($imageFileType);
echo "Response: ". in_array($imageFileType, $allowedTypes);
    if (in_array($imageFileType, $allowedTypes)) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "file=" . urlencode($target_file);
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "File is not an image or not allowed.";
    }
}


Now, If I try to upload a PNG, it works fine. However, if I create a simple PHP file and try to upload it, it won't upload as expected.
Now, if you change the magic bytes of the PHP file and try to upload it,it is still not uploaded as we are not checking on magic bytes but on the extension.
If I try to change the magic bytes and change the PHP file from hello.php to hello.php.png, it uploads fine.

But when I try to access the file using localhost/hello.php.png, it is still rendered as a png instead of a PHP.
What is missing here? I see online tutorials where if we upload the file by changing hello.php.png it will be treated as a PHP as the magic bytes are PNG but the file is actually PHP. Am I missing something?

FWIW, this code is a compilation of all you can do wrong in a file upload script: do redundant checks (is request POST?) and omit vital ones (did the upload succeed?), use relative paths so you can never be sure of where files are saved, storing raw uploads in a public location, use user-supplied filename, do a more or less valid check for image but never use the result, generate 500 Internal Server Error for user errors... Why do people think that glorified predictive text knows how to code?

I would like to upvote Alvaro's comment 10 times, but I'm only allowed to do it once. This code is, indeed, junk. It's no better than beginner guesswork made by pasting together bits of code they don't really understand. AI as a programmer is at about the level of someone who has been coding for a week.

Remember, chatGPT just knows how to put words in the right order so they sound coherent and plausible in a sentence (or in a computer program, which is also a language of sorts). Its primary skill is having a nice conversation with you. A secondary skill is sometimes being able to create meaningful content based on what it has scraped from elsewhere. But as they say...garbage in, garbage out...and it often doesn't know the difference. It can't replace your ability to write code. It can sometimes speed it up, if you know how to check that what it produces makes sense.

P.S. You should be aware that AI-generated content is banned on Stackoverflow - precisely because of this kind of issue...people get what looks like plausible output, but is in fact largely nonsense, and then it wastes everyone's time trying to unpick it again. Decent file upload and validation scripts abound on the internet already, it's not so hard to re-use proper content written by knowledageable humans, rather than what is, at the end of the day, just a somewhat sophisticated guessing tool.

Take a look at Full Secure Image Upload Script, for example. Written by actual people, with actual knowledge.

To have hello.php.png executed as PHP script you need that your web server is configured to do so. One possible way is to use Apache HTTP Server and use the AddHandler directive to identify scripts:
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

or:
AddType application/x-httpd-php php

As documentation warns:

The extension argument is case-insensitive and can be specified with or without a leading dot. Filenames may have multiple extensions and the extension argument will be compared against each of them.

For that reason, the PHP manual recommends this other mechanism:

Tell Apache to parse certain extensions as PHP. For example, let's
have Apache parse .php files as PHP. Instead of only using the Apache
AddType directive, we want to avoid potentially dangerous uploads and
created files such as exploit.php.jpg from being executed as PHP.
Using this example, you could have any extension(s) parse as PHP by
simply adding them. We'll add .php to demonstrate.
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>


So this is basically a specific exploit on a specific vulnerable setup.
